# Inserting a blank left starting page in a Koma-script book

Tags: page-breaking, koma-script, blank-page, scrbook

I am finishing my dissertation, and I'm using the Koma-script `scrbook` class. My text starts on a right page, which is exactly what I want, but for printing I need to add a completely blank, unnumbered left page to the beginning of the file. Using `\clearpage` or `\newpage`, however, produces two blank pages, the first one starting on a right page.

Of course I could use the resulting file and manually remove the first blank page in Acrobat, but I would really prefer to get it right at compilation, to minimize the risk of mistakes in printing. I'm including a mwe below.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\lipsum

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a standard preamble for my department that comes in a separate file, after which there needs to be a blank page. That file will be sent to the printers separately, and not by me.

Comment: The separate file contains two different title pages, one with a logotype, and a page with contact information for my department. These are standardized, and can't be easily replicated in Latex (at least not in the time I have left). Simply put, that is not an option for me. The only option other than solving the problem I posted is, as I said, to generate the version with two blank pages and remove one using Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @standard_error It would have been better to add this information to your question.

Comment: @Speravir I disagree. I think it's best to keep the questions as short and clean as possible, in order to make it helpful to others who might have the same issue.

Comment: No, it is always better to inform about the motivation for very unusual wishes. It would have saved us from almost all comments here. It would have been no problem to add the reason to the end _after_ your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Change the default behaviour of `scrbook` for starting new chapters: `\KOMAoptions{open=left}`.
2. Add something, that is not printed, like `\mbox{}`. Make sure the page number is not printed, too (pagestyle `empty`).
3. Insert the page break.
4. Reset the page counter to page 1.
5. At end of `\frontmatter`, directly before `\mainmatter` *(or in frontmatter directly before you start the next chapter like the table of contents or table of figures)* reset behaviour for starting chapter pages in `scrbook` to default: `\KOMAoptions{open=right}`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\KOMAoptions{open=left}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\lipsum[1-15]

\KOMAoptions{open=right}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[16-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `\mbox{}`, but it's just me.

Comment: @egreg I just didn’t think of this.

Comment: This still produces two blank pages, since scrbook insists on starting on a left page. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: @standard_error OMG, I first simply misread your question. See updated answer.